# Search on basis of drop down selected value in angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Dropdown:

```
<select class="form-control" id="column" ng-model="selectedcolumn" 
    ng-options="column for column in columns"></select>
```

I want to get the drop down value for search ,something like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="SearchValue.{{selectedcolumn}}" /> 
<tr ng-repeat="row in table | filter:SearchValue">
```

I want to make search for a perticular column, not for the whole table
and the column will be decided by the dropdown.

Comment: Make a fiddle of your code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `<input type="text" ng-model="SearchValue[selectedcolumn]" />`

Check the <kbd>[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/afQbDxDQrhLngHdzVbT8?p=preview)</kbd>